# Binding Up Nested UserComponent To it ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls, nested, viewmodel

I have a WFP Project and i am using MVVM Pattern.
I have AddressView User control which i used in CustomerView UserControl.

`<my:AddressVeiw Width="340" DataContext="AddressViewModel"/>`

My AddressVeiw userControl has a AddressViewModel and CustomerView has a CustomerViewModel

Code for CustomerViewModel

> ```
>         public DelegateCommand<object> SaveCommand { get; set; }
>
>  
>         private string firstName;
>
>         public string FirstName
>         {
>             get { return firstName; }
>             set { 
>                 firstName = value;
>                 RaisePropertyChanged("FirstName");
>                 SaveCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
>             }
>         }
>
>         private string lastName;
>
>         public string LastName
>         {
>             get { return lastName; }
>             set { 
>                 lastName = value;
>                 RaisePropertyChanged("LastName");
>                 SaveCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
>             }
>         }
>         private AddressViewModel addressViewModel;
>
>         public AddressViewModel AddressViewModel
>         {
>             get { return addressViewModel; }
>             set { addressViewModel = value; }
>         }
>
>         private string middleName;
>
>         public string Middlename
>         {
>             get { return middleName; }
>             set
>             {
>                 middleName = value;
>                 RaisePropertyChanged("MiddleName");
>                 SaveCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
>             }
>         }
>         private string fullName;
>
>         public string FullName
>         {
>             get { return fullName; }
>             set { 
>                 fullName = value;
>                 RaisePropertyChanged("FullName");
>             }
>         }
>         
>             
>         private void InitializeCommands()
>         {
>             SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnSaveCommand, CanSaveExcute);
>         }
>
>         private bool CanSaveExcute(object obj)
>         {
>             if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName) ||string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName))
>                 return false;
>             return true;
>         }
>
>         private void OnSaveCommand(object obj)
>         {
>             FullName = FirstName + " " + LastName;
>         }
>
>     }
> ```

Code for AddressViewModel

> ```
>     private ObservableCollection<Country> countryList = new ObservableCollection<Country>();
>
>     public ObservableCollection<Country> CountryList
>     {
>         get { return countryList; }
>         set { countryList = value; }
>     }
>
>     public DelegateCommand<object> SaveCommand { get; set; }
>
>     private void Load()
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             CountryList = (new CountryRepository().GetAll());
>         }
>         catch (Exception ex)
>         {
>
>             OnSetStatusBarText("Error: " + ex.Message.ToString());
>         }
>
>     }
>     private void OnSetStatusBarText(string message)
>     {
>         var evt = eventAgg.GetEvent<StatusBarMessageEvent>();
>         evt.Publish(message);
>     }
>     private void InitializeCommands()
>     {
>         SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnSaveCommand, CanSaveExcute);
>     }
>     private bool CanSaveExcute(object obj)
>     {
>
>         return true;
>     }
>
>     private void OnSaveCommand(object obj)
>     {
>
>     }
> ```

Some how i can hook my AdddressViewModel To my AddressView, Customer Works fine...
What Must be done to resolve this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a binding expression for the DataContext of your AddressView. Instead of this...

```
<my:AddressVeiw Width="340" DataContext="AddressViewModel"/>
```

...try this...

```
<my:AddressVeiw Width="340" DataContext="{Binding AddressViewModel}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks addressViewModel is not initializing. What can i do about that?

Comment: A simple fix might be to initialize the AddressViewModel property within the CustomerViewModel.

private AddressViewModel addressViewModel = new AddressViewModel;

Alternatively, set the AddressViewModel property when you create your CustomerViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but you need a binding:

```
<my:AddressVeiw Width="340" DataContext="{Binding AddressViewModel}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks but now addressViewModel is not initializing. What can i do about that?

Comment: @Tau can you explain what you mean by "not initializing"? Are you giving it a value when you initialize your CustomerViewModel?

Comment: I am using prism framwork and the constructor looks like this. How can i create a new instance?                                  public AddressViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IUnityContainer container, ILoggerFacade logger)
            : base(eventAggregator, container, logger){

Comment: Do you have the depdencies (IEventAggregator etc) in your CustomerViewModel's constructor? If so, just pass them in: `this.AddressViewModel = new AddressViewModel(eventAggregator, container, logger);`